# Is $ax+b=0$ still a linear equation if $a$ and $b$ are both $2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $ax+b=0$ still a linear equation if $a$ and $b$ are both $2$, like below?
$$2x+2=0$$

Comment: Yes!  Where did you get the question?

Comment: If you have multiple appearing variables in a definition, they are always allowed to equal each other unless it is explicitly said that them being equal is not allowed such as by saying "*let $a$ and $b$ be distinct real numbers*"  or "*let $a,b$ be real numbers such that $a\neq b$*" etc...

Comment: *Read the definition*  Some definitions in math vary depending on where you are.  If you wonder, go back to where you got the definition and see if it applies.  -1

Comment: add some context to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.$\text{                               }$

Answer (score 0):

Like the first answer said, yes it is.

The equation $2x+2=0$ can also be expressed as $x=-1$, which is a vertical line intersecting the $x$ axis at $(0, -1)$.